# Frequency analysis to determine low-pass cut off frequency

Tags: fft, filters, frequency-spectrum, lowpass-filter, preprocessing

I collected some data for a practical application, where the signal represents force data obtained from an impact of a punch against a force plate attached to a quasi-rigid rig (it moves once the impact occurs). I have a few questions to understand how to deal with my data.

Features of the signal:

the signal (sampling 1000Hz) has a length of 2 seconds, but the impact last about 60ms. The recording is 2s for practical reasons though. Therefore, before the impact a baseline is recorded (values close to zero), and after the impact vibrations occur until data set back to baseline levels. I need to figure out a reasonable cut-off frequency to use combined with a 4th order butterworth filter to properly filter the signal.

1. When exploring (FFT) the frequency of that signal should I use the whole 5s long signal or only the 30ms of interest? Due to sampling frequency, data points over 30ms maybe not enough?
2. Vibrations occurring due to the impact are not of interest, but the frequency is likely to be in part similar to the frequency of the portion of the signal of interest. How to deal with this? I could select from before the impact (arbitrary) to when the signal becomes zero after the impact. Then use from that point onwards to explore frequency of the unwanted signal only?
3. Impacts are at least 10 per subject, when exploring the frequency of that signal, should I average all trials and all subjects out to obtain an average frequency content or should I perform the analysis for each trial and subject indepedently?

Attached a figure of a typical signal (x = time; y = Newtons)

[image: Impact signal (first spike would be the portion of interest)]

[image: Power spectral density]

[image: Amplitude spectogram]

[image: 3D spectogram]

[image: Zoom the the portion of interest filtered at 80Hz Low Pass]

Comment: Out of interest: why do you need to do this with a fourth order butterworth?

Comment: and, much more importantly: "to properly filter the signal" for *which purpose*? What is it that you need to do with it afterwards? That defines all your needs!

Comment: In the literature force data are usually fitlered using a 4th order butterworth, but the low pass cut off frequency depends on a residual analysis. Thus, I just refer to other studies for the butterworth. However, for that signal, the typical frequency content is not well known in the literature. With this signal I need to look at peak value, impulse and time to peak value. These parameters are my outcome once the signal will be filtered.

Comment: Basically I need a good compromise to preserve both the signal magnitude and time domains.

Comment: what do you mean with "preserve time domains"? That's a bit of an uncommon thing to say, and honestly, I still don't know what's *important* for you about the signal.

Comment: Marcus, could you be more specific about what information you would need? I have explicitly reported what is important for me: peak value of the signal, impulse (area under the curve of the first spike), time to peak value. I'm looking for the right method to filter that signal to obtain these parameters with the lowest error possible (i.e. raw vs filtered signal). More explicit and clear than this it is very difficult for me to see what else is needed.

Comment: "preserve time domains" means to avoid that the filter will distort the time over which the impusle will be calculated, for example if with the raw signal the delta time is 30ms I'm expecting the filter giving a very close value and not e.g. 10ms or 60ms by oversmoothing the signal.

Comment: I can't really think about other features to describe in order for someone to be able to start proposing what procedure I should follow to filter this signal.

Comment: thanks! Sorry, maybe I was just a bit stuck in the head here. So: you say "time to peak", but I'm not sure time *from what* to peak? Ah and thanks for the clarification on what *impulse* is to you :) this means something else to me, and I thought it was the only thing I understood! So, OK, I'll be honest with you: I think your sampling rate might be too  low. I don't think you're reliably representing your signal, i.e. it boils down to "luck" whether you observe the actual peak amplitude or sample around it. I also think that fourth order butterworth is an insufficient choice here, but …

Comment: … but that choice might be made based on a *physical* understanding of the phenomenon that I as pure signal processor don't have. Can you maybe point me to the literature that introduces the butterworth as the appropriate filter here?

Comment: To select the sampling frequency (1000Hz), I have performed the same measurement sampling at 5000Hz and 10000Hz. I then performed a FFT and the result showed that most of the signal energy was always below 150Hz (for both 5Khz and 10Khz), therefore, 1000Hz was deemed enough according to the Nyquist rule.

Comment: The baseline (first 0.5s of the trace in the picture) will be averaged and using the rule of 3*standard deviation I will set a threshold to determine when the magnitude of the signal really starts raising (average value over 0.5s + 3*SD). This will be the beginning of my "time to peak value".

Comment: Most of the force data recorded on a force plate (ground reaction forces) are filtered using a 4th order Butterworth filter (biomechanics field). However, although many studies refer to other studies for that, I would not know whether a signal expert really reccomended this in a specific study about the use of the 4th order butterworth filter. So, I can't help with this and unfortunately I don't have any expertise on signal processing a part from basic concepts. That's why I'm looking for help.

Comment: I'm open to listen and follow intruction to filter the signal from scratch. The figure shows the raw signal. Via e-mail I can share data.

Comment: Ah that's pretty cool; can you add a plot of the FFT's magnitude, maybe of all, just for reference? My suspicion is that physically, you basically excite a very finite number of oscillations, and the peak happens when all these combine "same-phased" at your sensor. In a sense, the object you're hitting acts just like filter yourself, and what you're seeing is as close as it gets for a group delay of that system. That's why I was a bit skeptical of the butterworth: You'd ideally build a filter that has *constant group delay* over all frequencies, to avoid time dispersion; butterworth doesn't

Comment: have that property. Anyway, what might be a good approach: take successive *short-time fourier transforms*; my guess is that a *periodogram* built from these will show you the dominant frequencies you'd want to let through.

Comment: Is there a way I can add further figures here? It seems I can't do it in the comment box.

Comment: you should always be able to edit your question; add a link to your image (upload on imgur.com) if you can't add more figures yourself; I'll then convert that link to an embedded figure for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think you will get almost the same amount of frequency content for both the cases (fft of 60 ms and fft of 2 sec). The time series indicates that only from 0.6 to 1.2 sec there is vibration. But it's better to use the full signal while doing the FFT as there is no fear of losing any data. If you cut some portion from the time series, you have to be careful about choosing the window (use cosine tapering not rectangular window) as edging effect may be introduced into your frequency content.
2. Sorry, I didn't get the question. Could you please rephrase it?
3. I think that for all the trials, the time series would be different. Therefore, it is not recommended to average all the time series. It is better to analyze all the time sequences and obtain the frequency contents. If dominant frequencies for all the trials are similar, then the average frequency can be calculated. If not, you can try to find out the reason e.g. inconsistency in the sample material etc.

Comment: 2. I meant that the natural frequency of the system may overlap the frequency of the signal generated by an external factor (i.e. impact of an object). Is this a problem? Am I adding noise in this case?

Comment: 1. Thanks that is of help. It practically helps understanding how to procede with the raw signals.

Comment: I don't think that the frequency of the system is modified by this impact. Because impact means you are initiating the vibration of the system by only imparting an initial velocity.

Comment: 3. As for answer 1., very helpful for those like me unfamiliar with signal processing. Yes time series will be slighlty different for each trial/subject. However, a further question promoted by your answer... how to determine objectively the dominant frequency? What is for you the dominant frequency of the signal showed above based on the power spectrum plots attached?

Comment: Correct, I initiate the vibration with the impact and I was wondering whether I should make sure that I cut off the frequency of the system when the impact is over but the system will keep vibrating? This because I just care about the signal from beginning of impact till its end, nothing else. But apparently it is not a problem if I got you right.

Comment: The peaks in the FFT are considered as dominant frequencies. The FFT of the given signal has 5 peaks, that means the system has at least 5 number of modes. Among them, 2 of those are closely spaced modes. 1 & 2, 3 & 4 are closely spaced as you can see. For more details, you can google vibration more specifically vibration of continuous systems as you are determining vibration of plates.

Comment: For the last question in the comment, analyze the whole signal. The impact does not matter. You got me right... :)

Comment: Thanks. That clarify several aspects. Is the 5th peak the one close to 150Hz for you? Finally, to go back to the original problem, how to filter that signal?

Comment: No. The 5th peak is around 65 Hz I guess, if you provide the FFT plot in grids then I will be able to tell the 5 peaks from your fft

Comment: That's fine it was just to make sure that the bumo at 150Hz is meaningless, is that the case?

Comment: As the FFT magnitude around 150 Hz is pretty small, those can be considered as noise frequencies.